# Why is my C program behaving differently based on the directory it is executed from?

Tags: c, directory

This is driving me crazy.  I wrote a program that accepts user input for a file name. It operates as intended when executed in my ~/documents/cs directory, yet it fails in my ~/documents/cs/assign5 directory.  This makes absolutely no sense to me at all.  Why would a program behave differently based on the directory it is in?

Good output from execution in parent directory:

```
./a.out - file2
Enter the filename: file1
FILE1
FILE2
```

Bad output from assign5 directory:

```
./a.out - file2
Enter the filename: file1
file1
n: No such file or directory
```

I even tried renaming the assign5 directory to something else, and it worked fine.

The program basically takes two command line arguments.  If a "-" command line argument is present, it asks for a file name.  It then prints the contents of both files to standard out.  Here is where the program is failing (only in the assign5 directory...).  It seems that when the program is run in the assign5 directory, the userInput variable is storing the value "n" instead of "file1".  WHY!?

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0) // use standard-in for input file 1
        {
            printf("Enter the filename: ");
            fflush(NULL);
            read(STDIN_FILENO, userInput, sizeof(userInput));
            userInput[strlen(userInput)-1] = '\0';
            if((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
            {
                perror(userInput);
                exit(1);
            }
```

---

UPDATE:

I ran the exact same code on a remote linux server in a directory called "assign5" and it compiled and executed as intended.  So, what, is something wrong with my computer?

Comment: That code is fraught will peril. I would avoid using read() in this application.

Comment: If you do use read, it returns a value. Use it.

Comment: strlen() again.  Nearly every code posted with that call in it has null-terminator issues as a root cause of problems.

Comment: remove the `-1` from the `userInput[strlen(userInput)-1];` function, see my answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `read`. It screws up all your I/O unless you know what you are doing.

`strlen` on input returned from `read` will at best lead to a `SIGSEGV` at worst to undefined behaviour like what you are observing. Use `scanf`.

```
scanf("%s", userInput); // will add a null terminator itself
```

If you really have to use `read` then you need to do the job `scanf` does for you manually:

```
// reserve space for the null terminator
int bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, userInput, sizeof(userInput) - 1);
if (bytes_read < 0) {
    perror("read");
    abort();
}         

// add the null terminator
userInput[bytes_read] = '\0';

// you will most likely have a newline in the input
while (isspace(userInput[bytes_read - 1]))
     userInput[--bytes_read] = '\0';

char * filename = userInput;

// you may have preceding spaces
while (isspace(*filename))
     filename++;
```

Also note that for undefined reasons `read` may return before the entire input was read in which case you should ideally be calling it again until it returns 0. `scanf` would do that all for you.

Comment: @Smith Then you need to use it's return value! It will return the amount of characters read. make sure to trim off any newlines (`isspace`) and add a null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the last char in your string with '\0' instead of appending '\0' to the end as I suspect you intend:  Change this line:

```
userInput[strlen(userInput)-1] = '\0';
```

to:

```
userInput[strlen(userInput)] = '\0';
```

I do not have linux, or unix loaded, but this windows code is small and will illustrate better what I am suggesting:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void)
{
    DWORD len=260;
    LPTSTR lpBuffer;
    lpBuffer = malloc(260);
    GetCurrentDirectory(len, lpBuffer);

    lpBuffer[strlen(lpBuffer)]=0; //This works (although not necessary here
                                  //as GetCurrenentDirectory appends a '\0'
                                  //however, it is safe to do)

    lpBuffer[strlen(lpBuffer)-1]=0; //This will destroy the path information
                                    //by removing the last necessary char from 
    return 0;                       //your path string
}
```

Comment: As noted above, you cannot use strlen on output from read as it is not null-terminated.